# Swap words in sentence in "C"

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I've got an assignment from school in which I have to make a project which takes arguments from CMD, every argument has two words in it separated by `/`, we then insert the sentence and the program should find all occurrences of the first word and replace it with the second, I'm just trying to make it work using `strtok_r`.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    char *token;
    char *token2;
    char veta[1000];
    int i, j, k;
    int err;
    char *saveptr1, *saveptr2;

    if (fgets(veta, 1000, stdin)) {
        token = strtok_r(veta, " \n", &saveptr1);
        k = 1;
        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("Cycle %d: \n", k++);
            printf("%s\n", token);
            for (i = 1; i < args; i++) {
                token2 = strtok_r(argv[i], "/", &saveptr2);
                printf("%s ", token2);
                token2 = strtok_r(NULL, "/", &saveptr2);    
                printf("%s \n", token2);
            }   
            token = strtok_r(NULL, " \n", &saveptr1);
        }   
    }
    return(0);
}
```

when I type arguments into the CMD and insert sentence with for example four words, 4 cycles are executed but the output is not as I want it to be... For example when I give these arguments : `hi/hello how/good no/yet` and insert sentence the output is:

```
Cycle1: 
(first word of sentence)
hi hello
how good
no yet
Cycle4: 
(second word of sentence)
hi (null)
how (null)
no (null)
Cycle4: 
(third word of sentence)
hi (null)
how (null)
no (null)
Cycle4: 
(fourth word of sentence)
hi (null)
how (null)
no (null)
```

when it should be this:

```
Cycle1: 
(first word of sentence)
hi hello
how good
no yet
Cycle4: 
(second word of sentence)
hi hello
how good
no yet
Cycle4: 
(third word of sentence)
hi hello
how good
no yet
Cycle4: 
(fourth word of sentence)
hi hello
how good
no yet
```

I may not be able to fix it, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strtok_r()` changes its input string in such a way that you cannot reuse it in a loop (`"foo bar"` ==> `"foo\0bar"`). Inside the loop copy `argv[i]` and use the copy instead.

Comment: If your school is teaching you to use conio.h, consider dropping out.

Answer (score 0):

As said i a remark `strtok_r` modify its first argument, you need to first save the words from *argv*

I also encourage you to not modify the *argv*, and to check the arguments are correct checking the result of `strtok` or `strtok_r`

---

You can do for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char ** first = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(char *));
  char ** second = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(char *));
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i != argc; ++i) {
    char * s = strdup(argv[i]);

    if (((first[i - 1] = strtok(s, "/")) == NULL) ||
        ((second[i - 1] = strtok(NULL, "/")) == NULL)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid argument '%s'\n", argv[i]);
      return -1;
    }
    /* debug */
    else
      printf("first[%d]='%s' second[%d]='%s'\n", i-1, first[i-1], i-1, second[i-1]);

  }

  /*
  here you read sentences and do the substitutions
  */

  /* free resources */
  for (i = 0; i != argc - 1; ++i) {
    free(first[i]);
  }
  free(first);
  free(second);

  return(0);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
/tmp % ./a.out hi/hello how/good no/yet
first[0]='hi' second[0]='hello'
first[1]='how' second[1]='good'
first[2]='no' second[2]='yet'
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out hi/hello how/good no/yet
==29457== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29457== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29457== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29457== Command: ./a.out hi/hello how/good no/yet
==29457== 
first[0]='hi' second[0]='hello'
first[1]='how' second[1]='good'
first[2]='no' second[2]='yet'
==29457== 
==29457== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29457==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29457==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 73 bytes allocated
==29457== 
==29457== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29457== 
==29457== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29457== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

---

Note it is possible do do

```
  char * first[argc - 1];
  char * second[argc - 1];
```

rather that to allocate *first* and *second* in the heap, but there arrays have an unknown size in the stack at compile time and I encourage you to not use that way